# In Python, why are variables defined in a compound statement not local to the statement?

Tags: python

I come from C++ background. One of the things I enjoyed was having a small scope for variables defined in compound statements such as a loop. In Python, compound statements [do not form a block](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#structure-of-a-program) and a variable defined in a [suite](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#structure-of-a-program) is accessible outside of the compound statement. What is the rationale for this?

Comment: There are only a few things I dislike about Python's design, and the problem you describe is one of those. I wish this [code](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw1jTiksBCAqKMvNKNDI1ueAMrkQFWwVjrpTUNIU0jSQUZYmaXGkappr//wMA) would throw 2 errors, or at least warnings. Tighter scopes would lead to fewer surprises and bugs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of Python's language design details are recorded in PEP documents - this one seems to cover the rules around the relationship between variable names and scope: https://peps.python.org/pep-0227/#rebinding-names-in-enclosing-scopes

> There are technical issues that make it difficult to support rebinding of names in enclosing scopes, but the primary reason that it is not allowed in the current proposal is that Guido is opposed to it. His motivation: it is difficult to support, because it would require a new mechanism that would allow the programmer to specify that an assignment in a block is supposed to rebind the name in an enclosing block; presumably a keyword or special syntax (x := 3) would make this possible. Given that this would encourage the use of local variables to hold state that is better stored in a class instance, it’s not worth adding new syntax to make this possible (in Guido’s opinion).

Comment: There is already `:=` in Python, which is the assignment *operator*.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning The assignment operator is much newer than the quoted PEP. (The quoted PEP is from 2000, while the assignment operator was introduced in PEP 572 from 2018.)

Comment: Note also the PEP predates the `nonlocal` keyword, which is exactly the mechanism Guido didn't want to add.